# Tipo de expressão condicional não pode ser determinado porque não há conversão implícita entre "<nulo>" e "DateTime"

Tags: c#

Segue código:

```
string data_string = "17/01/2018";
DateTime? data = data_string == string.Empty ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(data_string);
```

Recebo erro:

> Erro  CS0173  Tipo de expressão condicional não pode ser determinado
>   porque não há conversão implícita entre "nulo" e "DateTime"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrito ao erro específico da pergunta o que falta é uma conversão da classe `DateTime` resultado do `Convert.ToDateTime()` para a classe `DateTime?`.

Mas aconselho um tratamento a mais, não é só porque a string não é vazia que ela possui um valor que pode ser convertido para `DateTime`.

Veja:

```
string data_string = "teste";
DateTime data_parsed;
DateTime? data = DateTime.TryParse(data_string, out data_parsed) ? (DateTime?)data_parsed : null;
```

Dessa forma `data` ainda é `null` e sua rotina seguirá sem mais problemas.

Se você fizer como sugeriu em sua resposta, se a conversão não obtiver êxito, você receberá um erro.

```
string data_string = "Dezessete de Janeiro de Dois Mil e Dezoito";
DateTime? data = data_string == string.Empty ? null : (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(data_string);
```

> A cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como um DateTime válido. Há
>   uma palavra desconhecida que começa no índice 0.   +
>   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(string,
>   System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo,
>   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles)   +
>   System.Convert.ToDateTime(string)

Claro que eu usei um exemplo absurdo e que dificilmente aconteceria em sem programa por outras validações e restrições da entrada. Mas em arquiteturas mais complexas, generalizações e desacoplamento isso poderia vir a dar alguma dor de cabeça.

Por isso é bom dar mais atenção aos detalhes, a solução nem sempre é a resposta e nunca confie nos seus dados de entrada.